# Polymorphism and casting problem

Tags: c#, polymorphism, abstract-methods, abstract-class

In order to explain my problem here is an example

```
namespace CheckAbstarct
{

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myAbstarctClass mac1 = ObjectFactory.ObjectCreator("aaa");
        myAbstarctClass mac2 = ObjectFactory.ObjectCreator("bbb");
        mac1.changeMyString();
        mac2.changeMyString();
        string myString = (string)mac2.returnMyObject();
        DateTime myObject = (DateTime) mac1.returnMyObject();

        object obj1 = mac1.returnMyObject();
        object obj2 = mac2.returnMyObject();

        myMethod(obj1);  //---> This is not compiling
        myMethod(obj2);  //---> This is not compiling

        myMethod(myString);  //---> works fine
        myMethod(myObject);  //---> works fine

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static void myMethod(DateTime dt)
    {
    }
    public static void myMethod(string st)
    {
    }
}
abstract class myAbstarctClass
{
    protected string mMyString;
    public myAbstarctClass()
    {
        mMyString = "myAbstarctClass ";
    }
    public abstract void changeMyString();
    public abstract object returnMyObject();        
}

class MyNewAbstractClass1 : myAbstarctClass
{
    DateTime mObject;
    public MyNewAbstractClass1(string myString)
    {
        mMyString = myString;
        mObject = new DateTime().Date;
    }
    public override void changeMyString()
    {
        mMyString += " MyNewAbstractClass1";
        Console.WriteLine(mMyString);
    }
    public override object returnMyObject()
    {
        return mObject;
    }
}

class MyNewAbstractClass2 : myAbstarctClass
{
    string mString;
    public MyNewAbstractClass2(string myString)
    {
        mMyString = myString;
        mString = mMyString;
    }
    public override void changeMyString()
    {
        mMyString += " MyNewAbstractClass2";
        Console.WriteLine(mMyString);
    }
    public override object returnMyObject()
    {
        return mString;
    }
}

static class ObjectFactory
{
    public static myAbstarctClass ObjectCreator(string myString)
    {
        switch (myString)
        {
            case "aaa":
                return new MyNewAbstractClass1(myString);
            case "bbb":
                return new MyNewAbstractClass2(myString);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}    
}
```

My problem is that in Main() I don't know what type the returnMyObject() method returns so I can't send it to MyMethod. Is there a way to cast the objects ??

Comment: Maybe you should use (typeof(obj1))obj1?

Comment: The problem you're having is a symptom of bad design - it isn't really how Polymorphism is supposed to be used. Inheritance is meant to be an "is-a" relationship (eg. `MyNewAbstractClass1` IS-A `myAbstarctClass`, `MyNewAbstractClass2` IS-A `myAbstarctClass`). Any functions that operate on the abstract type or any of its sub-types should be able to do so without knowing the specific type of the object (and in your case should list `myAbstarctClass` as the parameter type representing the object). Not needing to know the actual type is the real power behind Polymorphism.

Comment: So what is your suggestion to this problem. What solution would you consider as a good design to this kind of problem?

Comment: I think the design is so purposely artificial that you can't judge it here. But @Matthew is right that in a good design this exact problem would almost never  come up.

Answer (score 5):

Because in your design of `returnMyObject()` you went back to the most common `object` references, you will have to find out in runtime:

```
if (obj1 is string)
     myMethod((string)obj1);  //--->cast it 
else if (obj1 is DateTime)
     myMethod((DateTime) obj1);
```

Comment: @Gage: I was trying to show a pattern with 2 types. string is a bit privileged, didn't want to use that here. And ToString is not really better or faster here.

Answer (score 4):

You could check the object's type at runtime:

```
public static void myMethod(Object o)
{
    if (o is DateTime)
        myMethod((DateTime)o);
    else if (o is string)
        myMethod((string)o);
}
```

Although in your case, you might just as well pass a `myAbstarctClass` instance to `myMethod`, and then call `returnMyObject()` there.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use dynamic feature from C# 4.0 or change design to utilize some kind of double dispatch technique

```
        dynamic obj1 = mac1.returnMyObject();
        dynamic obj2 = mac2.returnMyObject();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Polymorphism mechanisms so you don't need to know the type of object.

Make `myMethod` an abstract method of `myAbstarctClass` and provide implementations in both `MyNewAbstractClass1` and `MyNewAbstractClass2`.

Modify `myAbstractClass1.returnMyObject()` to return `myAbstarctClass` (not `object`).

The test code in `Main` can then be written:

```
...
myAbstarctClass obj1 = mac1.returnMyObject();
myAbstarctClass obj2 = mac2.returnMyObject();

obj1.myMethod();        // calls MyNewAbstractClass1.myMethod()
                        // no if statement required!

obj2.myMethod();        // calls MyNewAbstractClass2.myMethod()
                        // no if statement required!

Console.ReadKey();
```

**Edit:** This can be further simplified, since the `returnMyObject()` methods are no longer necessary - they just return the object you already have. The test code is now simply:

```
mac1.myMethod();
mac2.myMethod();

// etc...
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thanks but the idea is that MyMethod is a method that should work on information (in the futur)  that  I don't want the myAbstracts object to know about

Comment: Without any information about what myMethod is doing it's rather difficult to provide a reasonable solution to your problem. I have one other idea though, which I'll post as a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to either create switch with all possibilities, or something like `Dictionary<Type, Delegate>`

or you can just make myMethod(object obj)

it's called Multiple dispatch (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) and there are some libraries that can do it

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be using your class as a container for a type (eg. `DateTime`, `string`), perhaps Generics would a be better choice than Inheritance:

```
namespace CheckAbstract
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            myTemplateClass<DateTime> mac1 = new myTemplateClass<DateTime>(new DateTime().Date);
            myTemplateClass<string> mac2 = new myTemplateClass<string>("cat dog");

            mac1.changeMyString();
            mac2.changeMyString();
            string myString = (string)mac2.returnMyObject();
            DateTime myObject = (DateTime) mac1.returnMyObject();

            myMethod<string>(myString);
            myMethod<DateTime>(myObject);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void myMethod<T>(T obj)
        {
        }
    }

    class myTemplateClass<T>
    {
        T mObject;
        string mMyString;
        public myTemplateClass(T init)
        {
            mMyString = init.ToString();
            mObject = init;
        }
        public void changeMyString()
        {
            mMyString += " " + mObject.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(mMyString);
        }
        public T returnMyObject()
        {
            return mObject;
        }
    }
}
```